# warning for the user to install .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

If i create a .net application then it requires .net installed in clients pc to work. So is there any method so that when i run the my application in a PC which does not have .net installed will give an warning message as ".net not installed,Please install it" . Can include it in my .net application itself so that anyone trying to use it without .net can get the message about what he has to do.

Comment: Have you tested this? It already should work without you having to do anything.

Comment: Add an install project to your solution and create an msi installer. Set .net package as a requirement.

Comment: Read this article , will will give you a details idea of Deployment with .Net! [HOW TO: Distribute the .NET Framework with a Visual Studio .NET Deployment Project](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733)